# How to parallelize increasing size for loop

Tags: c++, cuda

Here is our piece of c++ code which we want to parallelize on the gpu:

```
#include <array>
#include <vector>
#include <bitset>

#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>

#define NW 8 // use bitvectors of d=NW*32 bits, example NW=8

using namespace std;

using std::uint32_t; // 32-bit unsigned integer used inside bitvector
using std::size_t;   // unsigned integer for indices

// type for bitvector
typedef array<uint32_t, NW> bitvec_t;
typedef vector<bitvec_t> list_t;


void substract_list(const list_t& L)  {
// go over all unique pairs 0 <= j < i < L.size()
for (size_t i = 1; i < L.size(); ++i) {
    for (size_t j = 0; j < i; ++j) {
        size_t w = 0;

        for (size_t k = 0; k < NW; ++k) {
            w += an_array[i][k] - an_array[j][k];
        }
        cout << w;
    }
}
```

Our goal is to optimize this code and make it work on the gpu. What we currently don't know how to do is how to parallelize the second for loop, as this for loop increases in size and this would result in an increasing amount of threads which is not optimal for cuda programming. So our question, is it possible to parallelize an increasing for loop and if so do you guys have tips on how to do it?

edit:
added extra code.

Comment: is there any relation between `NW` and `L`?

Comment: can you flatten the loop such that the expresion in the body depends only on a single index?

Comment: @Love Coding, there is indeed. L is an array<uint32_t, NW>, where NW is a constant of how many 32 bitsstrings there are in the array L. -edit an_array is of the same type, array<uint32_t, NW>.

Comment: At least you can escape the whole loop for values `i = 0` and `i = 1`. Therefore, you can start from `i = 2`.

Comment: What have you got so far?  The obvious solution is to have a constant L.size() threads, and have L.size() - i of them do nothing.

Comment: @Martin Bonner So far we are only doing the operation of the inner loop on the gpu with as you suggest a constant size of L.size() with L.size() -1 doing nothing. It is indeed a solution, but with L.size()-i doing nothing you are not using the gpu to its full potential and the goal is to optimize the program as much as possible.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to include that information - ideally showing the code.  Also, typically how big is L.size() and NW?

Comment: @MartinBonner L is typically of size 10000 and NW is for testing of size 8

Comment: where goes w in the end?

Comment: @RegisPortalez for now we cout the total value of w at the end

Comment: For readability, it might be worth to make `bitvec_t` a true class, with a `sum()` method that adds all `NW` members.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The loop can be decomposed into

```
// the first addition part
for (size_t i = 1; i < L.size(); ++i)
{
    for( size_t k = 0; k < NW; ++k )
    {
        w += i * an_array[i][k];
    }
}

// the second subtraction part
for (size_t i = 0; i < L.size(); ++i)
{
    for( size_t k = 0; k < NW; ++k )
    {
        w -= (size-1-i) * an_array[i][k];
    }
}
```

The size increasing loop is annihilated. This approach can be easy implemented on GPU. 
In general, if you have a loop like your j-loop, you can multiply a if statement to these calculation. On GPU this approach is faster than if. This could looks like

```
for (size_t i = 1; i < L.size(); ++i) 
{
    for (size_t j = 0; j < L.size(); ++j)
    {
        size_t w = 0;

        for (size_t k = 0; k < NW; ++k)
        {
             w += an_array[i][k] - an_array[j][k] * (threadIdx.x < i);
        }
    }
}
```